# Can't able to show webpart at top of the page

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I am trying to add a webpart on top of the home page of a site programmatically. It's working but adding it at bottom.

```
  var page =context.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl
  ("/sites/testdevsite/18/SitePages/Home.aspx");
  var lwp = page.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared);


  string webpartxml = System.IO.File.ReadAllText
       ("C:\\Users\\shakm\\Downloads\\WebPart.webpart");
  WebPartDefinition wpd = lwp.ImportWebPart(webpartxml);
  lwp.AddWebPart(wpd.WebPart, "Header", 0);
  context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check in SharePoint Designer if Home.aspx actually has WebPart zone named *Header*.

I've created Team site in SPS2016 and default Home page placed in SitePages only has one WebPart zone named not *Header* but only *Bottom*:

```
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" ID="Bottom" CssClass="ms-hide" Title="loc:Bottom"><ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
```

WebParts and AppParts can exists not only in WebParts zones.

You can always add WebPart zone to your aspx page in any place inside:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
```

Comment: Can't see any web part zone in my page

Comment: can't insert web zone. Where to put it.

Comment: Use SharePoint Designer software to open site and edit Home.aspx page. There you can add <WebPartPages:WebPartZone/> in <asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">